# Using Manipulate and ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I'm fairly new to mathematica and found some solutions, but haven't been able to figure out why this doesn't work.

```
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[
    {{0, 0}, {Evaluate[xab[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yab[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xac[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yac[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xad[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yad[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xae[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yae[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xaf[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yaf[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xag[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yag[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xah[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yah[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xai[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yai[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xaj[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yaj[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xak[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yak[t] /. Sol]}, {Evaluate[xal[t] /. Sol], 
     Evaluate[yal[t] /. Sol]}, {1.2, 0}}, 
    Mesh -> Full, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Grey, Thick], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], 
  {t, 0, 30}]
```

Whenever I run it, the plot comes up with the t variable, but the only thing that is plotting is the first and last point.  Each point calls a function Sol which is another function that uses NDSolve.  I'm not sure how important that is because it's pretty long.  The values that return are:

```
Evaluate[xae[20] /. Sol]
Evaluate[yae[20] /. Sol]
```

Which will return {0.342717} and {-1.96098}, so x and y.

Comment: It's very difficult for us to help you without code that we can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look at {Evaluate[xab[t] /. Sol], Evaluate[yab[t] /. Sol]}. To plot, this will need to be a pair of points like {2,3}. If it is not a pair of points or if there are extra brackets, then you need to change the calculation or the formatting to make it a pair of plottable points.

Comment: Hmmm, well each one of the Evaluate[xae[t] /. Sol] return a value, but the answer is within {}.  That may be why it's not working.  Instead of being {2,3}, it'd be doing {{2},{3}}.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help Bill s.  So I did Part[Evaluate[yab[t] /. Sol],1] for everyone to return a value rather than a matrix I believe is what it's called.